# how to call an overloaded function with the spread operator

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I want to call the [pipe function](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/function.ts#L558) from fp-ts with the spread operator but it does not have an overload for this.

Instead, I am having to cast `pipe` to any and this looks ugly and harms readability.

Can I augment the existing type?

I have created this simple example and here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/spread-pipe-rzmdl?file=/index.ts:0-511).  The real-world example prohibits me from knowing exactly how many arguments I would be passing to pipe.

```
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/function";

const o = { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" };

type O = typeof o;
type G = (o: O) => O;

const set = (...getters: G[]) => {
  /*
  Expected 1-20 arguments, but got 0 or more.ts(2556)
  function.d.ts(225, 33): An argument for 'a' was not
  */
  return pipe(...getters);
  // this works but is ugly
  // return (pipe as any)(...getters);
};

const getters: G[] = [
  (o: O) => ({ ...o, a: "5" }),
  (o: O) => ({ ...o, b: "6" }),
  (o: O) => ({ ...o, c: "8" })
];

set(...getters);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a job for monoid.

```
import { foldMap } from "fp-ts/Array";
import { getEndomorphismMonoid } from "fp-ts/lib/Monoid";
import { identity, pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

const o = { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" };

type O = typeof o;
type G = (o: O) => O;

const monoid = getEndomorphismMonoid<O>();

const set = (getters: G[]) => pipe(getters, foldMap(monoid)(identity));

const getters: G[] = [
  (o: O) => ({ ...o, a: "5" }),
  (o: O) => ({ ...o, b: "6" }),
  (o: O) => ({ ...o, c: "8" }),
];

console.log(set(getters)(o));
```

I don't know if you are familiar with Monoid or not, but a monoid is typeclass have two functions.
`concat` and `empty` the concat is function that gets two value and concat it together and empty is when you the type does not have any value it will get empty value.

for example monoid for sum is like this

```
const monoidSum: Monoid<number> = {
  concat: (x, y) => x + y,
  empty: 0
}
```

you can use this `monoidSum` on `foldMap` of array and get sum of a list of integer.

here we use a function called `getEndomorphismMonoid` this is a function that is built in inside `fp-ts`. Endmorphism means a function that accept one argument for input and return the same type.

```
export interface Endomorphism<A> {
  (a: A): A
}
```

for concat it will pipe two function together and for the empty it use the `identity` function.

Comment: sir, thank you.  this has opened up new things for me to learn

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following?

```
const getters = [
  (o: O) => ({ ...o, a: "5" }),
  (o: O) => ({ ...o, b: "6" }),
  (o: O) => ({ ...o, c: "8" })
] as const;

const lotsOfO = pipe(o, ...getters);
```

`getters` has to be constant in order for typescript to infer the correct overload form, i.e. number of parameters in this case.

Comment: apologies, the example I gave was not very reflective of the real-world example.   I have updated the question and the codesandbox to something quite accurate now.

Comment: perhaps you can define fixed-length tuple first `type TupleOf<T, N extends number> = N extends N ? number extends N ? T[] : _TupleOf<T, N, []> : never;
type _TupleOf<T, N extends number, R extends unknown[]> = R['length'] extends N ? R : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>;` and cast it `return pipe(o, ...(getters as TupleOf<G, 19>))`
`